# change the mysql query into laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the sql query I want to change oit in laravel query
I have tried as

```
SELECT *
FROM chart
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(meeting_start_date), MONTH(call_start_date));



$query=DB::('chart')->where(DB::raw(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(meeting_start_date), MONTH(call_start_date))))->select('id')->get();
```

but getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'IN' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'` error

Answer (score 2):

The DB::raw method takes a string, so just enclose it properly:

```
$query=DB::('chart')->where(DB::raw("MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(meeting_start_date), MONTH(call_start_date)))")->select('id')->get();
```

Comment: getting operator does not exist character varying . so changed as $report_details=$report_details->where(DB::raw("MONTH::varchar(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(`meeting_start_date`), MONTH(`call_start_date`))"));

Comment: getting Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: ` character varying
LINE 1: ...th" in ($359) and MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), ... how to fix it